# Issue with using feature module services in nest js micro service controller

Tags: typescript, service, controller, nestjs

I have created a feature module "user". In this module i have created controller, model & services to connect to my postgres db.
However if i try to call userService from my feature module controller i get following error

```
[RpcExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'get_users' of undefined 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_users' of undefined
    at UserController.get (/usr/src/app/dist/user/controller/user.controller.js:23:33)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/context/rpc-context-creator.js:44:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/context/rpc-proxy.js:11:32
    at async ServerTCP.handleMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-tcp.js:55:54)
```

Below is my user.controller.ts file:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserI } from '../models/user.interface';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

export class UserController {

    private logger = new Logger('AppController');
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

    @MessagePattern('add_user')
    async add(user: UserI) {
        return this.userService.add(user);
    }

    @MessagePattern('get_user')
    async get() {
        return this.userService.get_users();
    }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from '../models/user.entity';
import { UserI } from '../models/user.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>
    ) {}

    add(user: UserI) {
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    get_users() {
        return this.userRepository.find();
    }
}
```

user.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserController } from './controller/user.controller';
import { UserEntity } from './models/user.entity';
import { UserService } from './service/user.service';


@Module({
    imports:[
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])
    ],
    providers: [UserService],
    controllers: [UserController]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal:true}),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true
    }),
    UserModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Are you possibly using webpack? Or something else that could be modifying the injection tokens? From the code you've shown, everything looks fine. Maybe adding `@Controller()` will fix it?

Comment: After adding @Controller that issue is fixed, but now i am getting different error message.

Comment: [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserController (?). Please make sure that the argument UserService at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
 @JayMcDoniel

Answer (score 0):

you should mark `UserController` as a controller to be able to inject thinks in it. Just add the `@Controller()` in your `UserController` class.
https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers

Comment: that error is solved after adding controller decorator. But now i am getting different error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks the `UserController` being picked up is from the `AppModule`. You should only define your providers and controllers in a single module file, otherwise you'll end up overwriting some of the metadata. Remove the `UserController` from `AppModule` and keep it only to `UserModule`. It should fix up your issue from there.

Comment: I didn't imported user controller in app module, currently its there only in user module as shown in description.

Comment: @McDoniel no need to have that controller in app module right, i already have it in user module.

Comment: @pkvd right, but your error is literally about not being able to resolve the dependencies of the `UserController` in the context of `AppModule`.